# map marker issue with infowindow with same infos

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

here is my code

```
 function buildMarkerMap(data, map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var node = data[i];
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(node.latitude, node.longitude);

            if (node.user_id != 0) {
                var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
            } else {
                var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');
            }



            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: node.php_date + ' ' + node.user_name + ' :' + node.user_id,
                maxWidth: 150
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                zIndex: i
            });

            marker.addListener('click', function() {

                infoWindow.open(map, this);
            });



        }
    }
```

that above map marker is working fin for finding the markers but in infowindow thy are an issue when clicking at the marker it shows the same infowindow of the last marker registered into DB

Can some one help to make info changes on every Different marker?

Comment: Why is this tagged as PHP?

Comment: https://www.codexworld.com/google-maps-with-multiple-markers-using-javascript-api/ - check this

Comment: You did code for single value. Please setup code with proper looping as above example link

Comment: thanks for reply 
can some one help to fix my code ihave try but the markers is gone